# Bootstrap modal issue with browser full screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullscreen

I have a div and I preview it fullscreen in browser (`requestFullScreen()`).
Everything works fine but when I open bootstrap modal it shows under fullscreen div (i mean the fullscreen stays over the modal) but when I cancel fullscreen I see modal.

Any ideas how to fix this ??

Comment: check out the demo, Surjith SM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, The `modal` div is out side `fullscreen` div.

So Please cut from there and paste the entire modal inside the `fullscreen` div

I don't know the reason, But it is working here.

```
<div id="fullscreen">
Lorem ipsum dolor 
<button class="btn launchConfirm">Launch Confirm</button>

<div class="modal fade"> //modal stuff here</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.modal').on('shown', function() {

$('body').css({
    overflow : 'hidden'
});
 }).on('hidden', function() {
$('body').css({
    overflow : ''
});
 });

 try this one
```

Comment: put the modal div inside full screen div

Comment: this is because when you making you div#fullscreen to view full screen on the whole page ,so that the modal div in the page falls behind and will not be loaded when you click launch confirm

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and the problem is with the `z-index` of your modal. Set the z-index to something like this.

`.modal { z-index:999999;}`

Comment: please make sure that z-index is being implemented and not overridden by default value if so then use `.modal { z-index:999999 !important;}`